# Close modal and scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$("#contact-form").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contact-section").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="saModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3>title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="contact-form" class="btn btn-default pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">Contact</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="contact-section">
<?php require 'contact.php'; ?>
</div>
```

When I click contact, The bootstrap modal closes as expected but doesn't scroll  to contact section, why?

Comment: Assuming you're trying to click the button through the overlay on a bootstrap modal, that's your problem. The click event is captured by the overlay to hide the modal. You need to click the button again once the modal has been hidden to raise the event on it. A better solution would be to hook to the `hide.bs.modal` event and perform the scroll in there

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok I'll give that a try

Comment: @ChetanGawai none

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `data-dismiss="modal"`

```
<button type="button" id="contact-form" class="btn btn-default pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" >Contact</button> 

$("#contact-form").click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contact-section").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My idea, like you can see in the comments, is based on listening for hide.bs.modal event.

My snippet:

```js
$('#saModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
  if ($('#saModal').attr('ModalXbuttonPressed') != undefined) {
    $('#saModal').removeAttr('ModalXbuttonPressed');
    return;
  }
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#contact-section").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});

$('#saModal button[class="close"][data-dismiss="modal"]').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#saModal').attr('ModalXbuttonPressed', true);
});


$("#contact-form").on('click', function(e) {
  $('#saModal').modal('hide');
});
```

```css
#contact-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saModal">
    Open saModal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="saModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3>title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="contact-form" class="btn btn-default pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">Contact</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="contact-section">
    <p>contact-section</p>
    <p>contact-section</p>
    <p>contact-section</p>
    <p>contact-section</p>
</div>
```

Comment: but this will hover down even if i click the x button

Comment: @Lynob Snippet updated. Now, clicking the x button, no scroll down will take effect. Thanks so much and let me know

Comment: thank you, now it works, and after fixing few stuff in my code, the first answer works too so i accepted it since both of them work but he has far less rep and his answer was posted first, but your answer works! thanks a ton!

Comment: I couldn't agree more with everything you said, such a gentleman!