# In Bootstrap how do I redirect to a section using a modal (without getting redirected to where the modal was opened)

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am building a simple front end site and I'm using Bootstrap for styling.
I have built a section using modals. The user clicks on a button to open the modal and then sees a centred modal.

**What I would Like**

I want to be able to allow the user to click a button at the bottom of the modal and be redirected to another part of the page and the modal close.

I have successfully been able to move the user to the new part of the page by using `<a>` tags, href and id's and also by using `onclick="window.location.href='#middle'"`, and have also been able to dismiss the modal.

**THE PROBLEM** is when the user clicks the button on the modal, they are redirected to where I want them to go to and the modal closes **BUT** then instantaneously the window moves back to the original place where the modal button was pressed.

I want to stop the moving back to the place where the original modal was clicked and leave the user at the place they got to when they clicked the button.

I have tried using `<a>` tags instead of `<button>` and it has the same effect.

Here is a working example jsfiddle showing the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/peamanschesthair/kdu5gno1/42/

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe scrollTop is what you are looking for.  Check out the solution at the bottom of this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614103/close-modal-and-scroll-to-div

Comment: Thanks. Why couldn't I find that thread?! I've been looking all day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout to delay the location change, after the modal `hide` event. To determine the element that triggered the dismiss, check the document.activeElement...

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var closeTrigger = document.activeElement.id
    if (closeTrigger === 'btnMove') {
        setTimeout(()=>{
          window.location.hash = '#middle'
        },400)
    }
})
```

**Demo:** https://codeply.com/p/WW9aB8OeNx

**Alternate option:** Set a data flag in the modal hide event if the btnMove has been clicked, then chain the hidden event and check the data flag...

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var closeTrigger = document.activeElement.id
    if (closeTrigger === 'btnMove') {
        this.data = 'move'
    }
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if (this.data === 'move') {
        setTimeout(()=>{
          window.location.hash = '#middle'
        },400)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that it continues with the location change even if the user dismissed the modal or clicked the x.

Comment: Thanks Zim, I like your idea. What I don't understand is when implementing it, why it is not repeatable? You can move the user once, but then I can't seem to do it again with this solution. Am I missing something? Thank you